# Cropping Image to any Shape Android

Tags: android, image, crop

So far, I am able to achieve the default crop options available in the devices. But my requirement is like cropping the image with 4 dots, so that any image can be cropped to any shape.

Any idea , how this can be achived. DocumentScanner application already uses this feature.

Comment: Got some ideas on the above,.. not sure if this will work out..but still.. 1. Get the copy of the Bitmap image. 2.Draw the same on the new canvas. 3. In that canvas, drawpaths , from which we can get the axis of the image. am i rite?Any suggesstions???

Comment: have you find any solution ?

Comment: please refer this, it allows to crop using 4 dots. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969028/crop-image-by-polygon-area#comment23190147_15969028

Comment: john sakthi can you explain your edits?